# Was there a real city on which the movie Nightmare on Elm Street was based?

Tags: film-location, a-nightmare-on-elm-street

Where was the house on Elm street filmed in the [*A Nightmare on Elm Street*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Nightmare_on_Elm_Street) and what city was it supposed to be in the movie?

This part of the film was that supposed to look like the 60s is a clue in the movie. I know it was said that the idea came from refuges that died in their sleep but I wasn't satisfied with that answer and wonder if it's possible that there is some truth that is deeper.

[image]

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/260/why-is-it-elm-in-a-nightmare-on-elm-street

Comment: the answer to this is in the very wikipedia page you link to *"The fictional address of the house that appears in the film is 1428 Elm Street; the actual house is a private home located in Los Angeles on 1428 North Genesee Avenue."*

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson can more tags be edited like history?

Comment: @Muze I wouldn't know which, it's not really about actual "historical accuracy", is it?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson you mean my answer? I spent days researching similarities in helltown, ohio. Some refugees dying of sleep deprivation doesn't seem to me like the only source of the authors material.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  The movie was based on many of Craven's childhood memories, all of which happened in Los Angeles, CA.  The initial concept was loosely based on [actual cases](https://medium.com/@arifakhtar/some-nightmares-are-real-the-mysterious-deaths-that-inspired-a-nightmare-on-elm-street-1cafb7450c78) of refugees from Laos, Cambodia and Vietnam having a series of terrifying nightmares and then dying in their sleep shortly thereafter.

Freddie Kruger was originally intended to be a child molester, but a spate of molestation cases had occurred during production and he didn't want to be accused of exploiting the cases.  The character's name was the name of a boy who had bullied Craven in Elementary School.

The decision to set the movie in a small town in Ohio, and on Elm Street, was made so that it had a broader appeal to rural Americans.

Comment: All the info collected in my answer is from Ohio. +1 thanks for answering

Comment: A spate of child abductions and sacrificial rituals. Nowhere in the film did it imply molestation,

Comment: Correct.  Because it was changed prior to filming.

Comment: Do you have more references on this?

Comment: @Muze - Outside of Wiki and its associated source links?  Not really.  But they all check out, so the Wiki wasn't just based on some guy's Fan Fiction.  This write-up seems to confirm most of the main points of my answer: http://screenprism.com/insights/article/what-inspired-a-nightmare-on-elm-street

Answer (score -2):

My answer is from unofficial sources and articles both fiction and nonfiction from what was said and not said. I am aware of the official answer given by Wes Craven but this is not that answer.

The fictional address of the house that appears in the film is 1428 Elm Street; the actual house is a private home located in Los Angeles on 1428 North Genesee Avenue."

I googled mapped street viewed it and added the picture below with the link to see the whole street.

Google's maps are slightly off but you can see the address on the door frame.

[https://www.google.com/maps/place/1428+N+Genesee+Ave,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90046](https://www.google.com/maps/place/1428+N+Genesee+Ave,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90046/@34.097073,-118.3582019,3a,30y,86.99h,93.35t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1swsGLcfjYjp8ZRIxgBmwVEQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2bec3354aedaf:0xad9fb660ecea86b3!8m2!3d34.0970733!4d-118.3578599)
[image]

Now in the movie it appears to be in the city of Springwood, Ohio from the newspapers from the movies.

There is no actual place in Ohio to come close to the city name Springwood in the movie.

Although, I did find this place called Helltown along a road called Riverview, previously Boston Township founded in 1775 is one of the nine townships of the Summit County, Ohio, United States, about 23 miles south of Cleveland.

The city slogan is a very similar match to the welcome sign in the movie. The city was shut down from all the Satanic worship and unsolved missing children from the 60s in that area and as rituals go ritual probably go back to 1775.

In 1974, President Ford signed a legislation that allowed the National Parks Service to buy the area and turn it into a national park. There was no real park ever made nor did it have any real unique features and never really became a park.

No spills or hardship and some of the houses where unusually extravagant for the area to be shut down the way it was. Maybe the majority of the people was just evil and as an extra measure they closed the land. I could not find any official reason why that location was chosen for a park.

The Army was called in to remove the people in that area.

[Video of locales being ran out of their homes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0D_lbXPVIQ)

I think some really evil cult shtuff when down by some evil people and they ment to stop it for ever. By some chance the land was damned they evacuated the area.

Remember the scene on the movie with the school bus.....the rusting bus in the picture(photoshoped) below was said in that area of a killing spree where at least a dozen children were hacked to death on a school bus. Don't fall asleep and miss your stop.

[image]

The sign above is the actual welcome sign but the picture was photoshoped. Notice the slogan for the movie compared to the one in Helltown.

One, two, they are coming for you
Three, four, better lock your door
Five, six, grab your crucifix
Seven, eight, gonna stay up late
Nine, ten, never sleep again

Children went missing at night while they were sleeping and taken to this church next to the bus where Rituals were done to them in the basement. I included another picture of the church before the city was shut down.

[image]

---

More Helltown, Ohio pictures:

[image]

[image]

Houses that was abandoned in the 90s look similar to the Elm Street in the movie.

[image]

[image]

The jail was the last part of the city to close in the 90s about 30 years after the city was closed. I could only imagine that the perpetrators were kept there until death.

[image]

Graves of children around an Elm tree.
[image]
The Old Boston Township High School

[image]
Notice the upside down crosses. Blueprints for this church was used across the US.

[image]

[image]
Photos of actual missing children from this town looks similar to the movie newspaper.

[image]
From the movie.

This would make a good bases for this horror movie. Exact detail are unconfirmed, but you can Google Helltown, Ohio and decide for yourselves.

Comment: You have some errors here.  The area was taken by the government due to local fears of urban sprawl and eventually became the Cuyahoga Valley National Park. Yes it actually does exist
The white house with the satellite dish is in East Cleveland and was abandoned during the housing crisis in the mid 2000s.  The next house is in Milan Ohio 62 miles from there.
The Elm street story wasn't based on a town but on LA Times stories in the 1970's about Southeast Asian refugees who were dying in their sleep after repeatedly suffering disturbing nightmares.

Comment: The Welcome sign of Helltown is a very bad fake.  There wasn't a population of 350,000 nor is the elevation of anything in Ohio 6,250 feet unless it's an airplane.  The highest point in the state is Campbell Hill at 1,550 feet. The church pictured is still in use.  It is the Mother of Sorrows Catholic church. If the architectural detail on the church is anything more than a detail then it would be the Cross of Saint Peter which is an inverted cross.  The park has a lot more than just a ski area: https://www.nps.gov/cuva/planyourvisit/outdooractivities.htm

Comment: The paper that has the story of two missing kids is also likely a fake.  If you look at the paragraphs on the lower left side they are lorem ipsum.  Dummy paragraphs in Latin often used in fake newspapers.

Comment: The Helltown legend is almost all fake. The church is the same one I mentioned above and the picture comes from Wikimedia commons here: https://bit.ly/2rc6Abd
The buildings and graffitied wall pic are in Atlanta and come from this article on how to do justice in at risk neighborhoods:  https://bit.ly/2jpfNc0
The one labeled Dormatory and the picture 2 below it are the Byberry Mental Hospital in Philadelphia as seen here https://bit.ly/2Fzycvf   The only real thing is that the government turned an area into a National Park and kicked people off the land.

Comment: @Legion600 if that whole area was cult worshiping elitist they would probably control the news papers at the time and ran any outsiders out of there area.  Nice house burned not recycled. Yes the stories are mostly fake on paper. It was the way people where handled, what was not said. The government sent in troops to clear the area. The place isn't worth a visit then or now. Why didn't the jail close till 30 years later?

Comment: it's fake.  That isn't a prison it is the Byberry Mental Hospital.  No cult.  No mystery.  Back to your original question though, It wasn't the inspiration for the town in Elm Street because there was nothing wrong with the town in Elm Street.  They used a fake town name so they wouldn't get sued.

Comment: Photoshop most likely, along with the bus and the building in the picture.

Comment: Your 17th link is missing, so the answer lacks a picture :)

Comment: None of this actually proves what you are saying.  This seems like a bunch of loosely connected "evidence"; much of which is suspicious.

Comment: No, I didn't watch an 18 minute long video, because answers should stand up relatively well on their own.  If the video has evidence supporting what you are saying, find their sources and include information from those, or at least explain how the video is able to make these conclusions.  (FYI, having pictures every couple sentences really breaks the flow of information and makes this harder to follow)

Comment: @Muze As I said last year, most of this is fake or internet clickbait. I'm disappointed this still part of your answer. If you want a good take down of this go here. http://www.ghostsofohio.org/lore/ohio_lore_36.html

Comment: @Muze Well the "answer" doesn't really draw any of this together convincingly, so I'll just keep the downvote and leave it at that I guess.

Comment: There are no real newspapers. Both of the newspaper pictures you posted are fakes. If you look at the paragraph to the left of the headline Two Children Missing in Boston Township you will see it is written in lorem ipsum. Dummy Latin text that is used to fill up space in the print industry. It is also used to fill up fake newspapers in movies. The fact that there are zero references to the FBI shooting 14 people at a compound in Ohio anywhere online is further evidence that this is just internet legend. It's fake.

Comment: @Muze This isn't the site for refuting urban legends. It shouldn't be the site for posting them either.